# Using string.TakeWhile() to cull unwanted strings from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have two pieces of code that I feel should produce identical results, but they don't.  I'd like to figure out why, because I would really rather use the simpler of the two.

I have an array of strings:

```
string[] strArray =
{
"$!set @a = ",
"\"=== Activate Response ===\"",
" ",
"\"2\"",
""
}
```

I want to cull the two empty (only whitespace) strings into a List

The first method is brute force, but does what I want:

```
List<string> culledList = new List<string>();
foreach (var str in strArray)
{
    var x = String.Compare("", str.Trim(), true);
    if (x != 0)
    culledList.Add(str.Trim());
}
strArray = culledList.ToArray();

Resulting in three strings:
"$!set @a = ",
"\"=== Activate Response ===\"",
"\"2\""
```

The second a bit more elegant, but it doesn't work right:

```
strArray = strArray.TakeWhile(str => String.Compare("", str.Trim(), true) != 0).ToArray<string>();

Resulting in two strings:
"$!set @a = ",
"\"=== Activate Response ===\""
```

I actually made the brute force method by interpreting what I thought the elegant method should be doing.
Any thoughts?

- Lee

Comment: [`TakeWhile` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-6.0): _"Returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true, and then skips the remaining elements."_ - it seems you want [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0): _"Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate."_

Comment: "Returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true, and then skips the remaining elements." So you'll probably only get the first one with `TakeWhile()` (if any). I would use `Where()`.

Comment: It's quite literally the first sentence on the page about TakeWhile()

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar - Who reads documentation when you can just ask StackExchange? :)  I did read the docs, I just was blind.  I actually stole this example from another StackExchange answer that I was looking at - I guess I just didn't read THAT question well enough.  I did the brute force thing myself when the answer I found didn't work.  Didn't even think about looking for ANOTHER C# trick. I've been doing this a long time, but C# seems to keep coming up with ways to do even the most bizarre things, and I've just really started with C#.  Anyway, thanks! - Digilee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOur elegant can be simplified even further (after subtituting `Where`, for `TakeWhile`

```
strArray = strArray.Where(s=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
```